# Gnome3 Multiple Monitors Catches

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome-3

I have 3 screens, and Gnome3 installed on Ubuntu with an odd problem that I'm hoping someone knows how to fix. On the MAIN MONITOR ONLY (whichever monitor I define as the primary in the display settings) - if I drag a window onto or off of that monitor onto another monitor - the screen will "catch" about halfway and hang - almost like it's stuck. It drives me nuts since the main monitor is where most of the apps open by default. Is this a setting somewhere? I have prowled and tried various things and can't fix it. It ONLY happens on the main screen - not the extra other monitors. Any ideas? I'm running Ubuntu 17.04, but I saw this on Ubuntu 16.10 before I upgraded.